# List certain taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I registered some taxonomies and want to retrieve their taxonomy labels to list a few of them. The list is not post or category related and could appear virtually anywhere (single, archive, etc.).

I want to create a variable/an array of the taxonomies in question so I can use it elsewhere:

```
$tax_names = array('tax_01', 'tax_02', 'tax_03');
```

This code works, but only outputs one taxonomy:

```
$tax_args = array(
  'name' => 'tax_01'
);

$output = 'objects';

$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $tax_args, $output ); 

if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->label . '</p>';
  }
}
```

This does not work:

```
$tax_args = array(
  'name' => $tax_names // using the array created above
);

$output = 'objects';

$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $tax_args, $output ); 

if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->label . '</p>';
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it anywhere like that you could create a function in the functions.php

```
function retrieve_my_terms() {

 global $terms;

 $terms = get_terms('taxonomy');

 foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $option = $term->name;
    return $option;
 }
}
```

And then in your php file you can call the function like

```
retrieve_my_terms();
```

EDIT:

You could try doing something like this - I haven't tested it properly but it might be helpful to you.

```
function retrieve_my_terms($termArray) {

  global $terms;

  $terms = $termArray;

  foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $option = get_term_by($term);
      return $option;
  }
}


$tax_names = array('tax_01', 'tax_02', 'tax_03');
retrieve_my_terms($tax_names);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works, but it returns the taxonomy terms. I want to echo the labels of the taxonomies stored in an array, for example:
`$tax_names = array('tax_01', 'tax_02', 'tax_03');`
Output should be taxonomy labels: Taxonomy 01, Taxonomy 02, Taxonomy 03.